# jQuery + Chrome incorrect scrollHeight

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a simple page with a content_row div preceding 3 content_window divs. When clicking on a content window, its content gets copied to the content_row div, and the div expands to fit the content that is pasted in. The whole process works great in FF and IE, and is based on the scrollHeight of the pasted content in the content_row to get the proper height (which is animated).

However, Chrome isn't giving me the proper scrollHeight during the $(".content_window").click function. However, it provides the correct scrollHeight when $(window).resize is called.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm completely puzzled because both functions get the exact same prop. However, I think Chrome might calculate the scrollHeight "too soon" in relation when the html is pasted in content_row.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B3BTh/

The jQuery:

```
$(".content_window").click(function(e) {
    var cwi = $(this).index(".content_window");
    var cri = Math.floor(cwi / 3);
    $(".content_row:eq("+cri+")").html($(this).html());
    var cri_height = $(".content_row:eq("+cri+")").find(".content_window_wrapper").prop('scrollHeight')+"px";
    $(".content_row:eq("+cri+")").stop().animate({height: cri_height,opacity: 1},1000);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".content_row:eq("+cri+")").offset().top}, 1000);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    $.each($(".content_row"), function(e) {
        $(this).height($(this).find(".content_window_wrapper").prop("scrollHeight"));
    });
});
```

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, create jsfiddle ? Thanks

Comment: I've added a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/B3BTh/

Comment: Not certain about requirement. Please clarify. clicking on 1st `content_window` results in text being displayed between images, clicking 2nd `content_window` displays image between `content_window`s ? perhaps, at least at jsfiddle, adjust `content_window` images to be able to determine distintion between images, and their results when clicked ? Thanks

Comment: Well, this is embarassing!
The code in the jsfiddle works just fine in chrome, but as a standalone page, the scrollHeight prop is not returning the proper value.